# Calculate $R^2$ longitudinal multilevel analysis

Tags: regression, panel-data, multilevel-analysis, r-squared

How can I calculate $R^2$ for multilevel longitudinal analysis without Level-1 variance in `R`? One predictor is a factor (Treatment: A, B, C).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It isn't just the usual calculation using the residual sum of squares and the total sum of squares?

Comment: My problem is about longitudinal multilevel analysis. Time is modelled on level 1. Time was dummy coded (baseline - post = D1 (time is fixed at post = 1), baseline - follow-up = D2 (time is fixed at follow-up = 1). It is a saturated model (i.e. a model without a level 1 residual). If the residual = 0, no sum of squares can be formed from it and consequently no R2 can be calculated. Is there another way to calculate the effect size for these particular models?

Comment: In addition, the treatment is also treated as a factor in that there are three underlying treatment forms. In many R2 calculations in R (e.g. Rights & Sterba), all variables except the grouping variable must be a numerical variable.